# how to create a function that gives a prime number + bool value?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I'm struggling since yesterday with this, how to create a function that has a list of prime numbers and returns "prime number + true/false"
ex:

2 true
3 true
4 false
5 true

it's in Swift 5, first func called `primecheck` is working great, the problem is in the second one `PrimeList`

```
func primecheck (numbers:Int) -> Bool{ 

    var prime = true

    if numbers == 1 || numbers == 0 || numbers == 2{
        prime = true

    }
    if numbers > 2{
        for i in 2...numbers - 1{
            if numbers % i == 0 {
                prime = false

            }

        }
    }
    if numbers == 1 || numbers == 0 || numbers == 2{
        prime = true

    }

    if numbers < 0{
        prime = false
    }
    return prime
}


func PrimeList(maxP:Int) -> [(num1:Int, num2:Bool)] {


    var primes: [(num1:Int, num2:Bool)] = []

    for i in 1...maxP {

        if primecheck(numbers:i){
            print(i)
            primes[i - 1] = (i, true)

        } else {
            primes[i - 1] = (i, false)
        }
    }
  //  isPrime[0] = true
  //  isPrime[1] = true

    return primes
}

print(PrimeList(maxP:20))
```

expected output:

```
print(primeList(maxP:20))
// 2 true
// 3 true

// 4 false
...
// 20 false
```

but always appears this error:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

Comment: Use `primes.append((i, true))` and `primes.append((i, false))` instead, or directly `primes.append((i, primecheck(numbers: i)))`

Comment: 0 and 1 are not prime numbers by definition

Comment: Let's simplify your case: `var array: [Int] = []; array[0] = 3` That's the same error, and in Console, there is also interesting message: "Fatal error: Index out of range". Read `array[0] = 3`, as: Give me the item at index 0, and replace it with value 3. Well, "Give me the item at index 0" causes the crash (and that log makes sense).

Comment: The easy solution here is of course to only include numbers that are prime numbers in the result array and forget about this boolean value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See bellow answer if it could make sense to you:

```
func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> String {

    return "\(number) \(number > 1 && !(2..<number).contains { number % $0 == 0 })"
}

func PrimeList(maxP:Int) {
    var array = [String]()
    for number in 0...maxP {
        array.append(isPrime(number))
    }
    print(array)
}
```

Call method:

> PrimeList(maxP: 20)

**Ans:**

> ["0 false", "1 false", "2 true", "3 true", "4 false", "5 true", "6
>   false", "7 true", "8 false", "9 false", "10 false", "11 true", "12
>   false", "13 true", "14 false", "15 false", "16 false", "17 true", "18
>   false", "19 true", "20 false"]

Comment: 0 and 1 are _not_ prime numbers

Comment: @mansonflirr if you found an answer that helped you solve this then mark it as accepted instead of posting a comment like this. This will help future readers who are facing a similar problem as yours and will of course be appreciated by the person who wrote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your program is crashing because you can't index into an empty array in Swift.  You should use `append` to add items to your array.

Instead of creating the array by appending items though, this is an ideal place to use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2908394-map):

```
func primeList(maxP: Int) -> [(num1: Int, num2: Bool)] {
    return (1...maxP).map { ($0, primecheck(numbers: $0)) }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`map` creates an array.  In this case, it takes each item from the range `(1...maxP)` and converts it using the provided closure into a *tuple* of the original value and the result of calling `primecheck` with that value.  The result is the desired array with the pairing of the values with bools indicating if they are prime.

---

Your `primecheck` function can be cleaned up by using `guard` to immediately `return false` for numbers not greater than `1`.  You can immediately `return false` if you find a number that evenly divides the input, otherwise `return true` if none are found.

```
func primecheck (numbers:Int) -> Bool {
    guard numbers > 1 else { return false }

    for i in 2..<numbers {
        if numbers % i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

**Notes:**

1. You can further optimize `primecheck` by abandoning the check for a divisor when `i * i > numbers`.  Add `guard i * i <= numbers else { return true }` at the top of the `for` loop.  Alternatively, make the upper end of your divisor range be `Int(sqrt(Double(numbers)))`.
2. `2...numbers - 1` has been rewritten as `2..<numbers`.
3. Function names should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) or [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce) methods to generate the primeList array of tuples.

Using `reduce(into:_:)`

```
func primeList(maxP:Int) -> [(num1:Int, num2:Bool)] {
    return (1...maxP).reduce(into: [(num1:Int, num2:Bool)](), { $0.append((num1:$1, num2:primecheck(number:$1))) })
}
```

And you don't need to check till `n-1` for finding whether a number is prime or not. You can check till the `square root` of `n`

```
func primecheck(number: Int) -> Bool {
    if number < 2 { return false }
    if 2...3 ~= number { return true }
    return !(2...Int(sqrt(Double(number)))).contains { number % $0 == 0 }
}
```